# How Create An Notification Swift Like WhatsApp Call FCM?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to make it so that when a client receives an FCM notification it becomes like a Whatsapp call with a custom sound like the picture below ?.

I've made fcm but only the notification with the ringtone "Cling" after that the notification is gone.

I want to make it like this any suggestions thank you.

[image]

Comment: You surely tried _something_. SO is not a free code writing website. Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `UNNotificationContentExtension`

[image]

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/unnotificationcontentextension

https://www.fabrizioduroni.it/2018/09/09/ios-notification-content-extensions.html

Comment: Have you the link or documentation for that Sh_Khan.

Comment: Ok Thanks You Ill try. If Work I'll back and make a green check.